# How to get value by multi-index with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I get the value from a dataframe by its multi-index?

For example I have a dataframe `mm`:

```
np.random.seed(1)
mm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2))
mm['A'] = np.arange(5)
mm['B'] = np.arange(5,10)
mm.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)

print mm

        0         1
A B                    
0 5  1.624345 -0.611756
1 6 -0.528172 -1.072969
2 7  0.865408 -2.301539
3 8  1.744812 -0.761207
4 9  0.319039 -0.249370
```

I want to get the value where A = 2, B = 7, how can I do that?

Is it possible to write a function like `get_value(mm, (2,7))`, then I can get the following result:

```
2 7  0.865408 -2.301539
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `mm.loc` to select rows by label:

```
In [28]: row = mm.loc[2,7]; row
Out[28]: 
0    0.865408
1   -2.301539
Name: (2, 7), dtype: float64

In [40]: np.concatenate([row.name, row])
Out[40]: array([ 2.        ,  7.        ,  0.86540763, -2.3015387 ])
```

Since `mm` has a MultiIndex, each row label is expressed as a tuple (e.g. `(2,7)`). When there is no ambiguity, such as inside brackets, the parentheses can be dropped: `mm.loc[2, 7]` is equivalent to `mm.loc[(2, 7)]`.

---

To get all rows where `B=7`, you could

- use
  [`pd.IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers):

  ```
  xs = pd.IndexSlice
  mm.loc[xs[:, 7], :]
  ```
- or the [`mm.query`
  method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

  ```
  mm.query('B==7')
  ```
- or [`mm.index.get_loc_level`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_loc_level.html) with `mm.loc`:

  ```
  mask, idx = index.get_loc_level(7, level='B')
  mm.loc[mask]
  ```
- or `mm.index.get_loc_level` with `mm.iloc`:

  ```
  mask, idx = index.get_loc_level(7, level='B')
  mm.iloc[idx]
  ```

Each of the expressions above return the DataFrame

```
            0         1
A B                    
2 7  0.865408 -2.301539
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu , but is it possible that I just give the second index? For example, I want to select all rows, where B=7?

Answer (score 8):

This returns your selection as a dataframe:

```
>>> mm.loc[[(2, 7)]]
            0         1
A B                    
2 7  0.865408 -2.301539
```

To get the index and values:

```
>>> mm.loc[[(2, 7)]].reset_index().values.tolist()[0]
[2.0, 7.0, 0.8654076293246785, -2.3015386968802827]
```

To get all values where the second item is 7:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> mm.loc[idx[:, 7], :]
            0         1
A B                    
2 7  0.865408 -2.301539
```